# How to add watemark in a video with ffmpeg, Python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, watermark

I would like to add a .png watemark with 50% opacity over all my video. I would prefer using a ffmpeg filter over merging the watemark image with video-to-be images.

```
audio = f'{PROJECT_PATH}/data/ppt-elements/audio_{file_id}.txt'
images = f'{PROJECT_PATH}/data/ppt-elements/images_{file_id}.txt'

image_input = ffmpeg.input(images, f='concat', safe=0, t=seconds).video
audio_input = ffmpeg.input(audio, f='concat', safe=0, t=seconds).audio

additional_parameters = {'c:a': 'aac', 'c:v': 'libx264'}

audio_input = ffmpeg.filter(audio_input, "amix", inputs=2, duration="longest")

watermark_file = f"{PROJECT_PATH}/data/logo/logo.png"

# add watermark
watermark = ffmpeg.input(watermark_file)

inputs = [image_input, audio_input, watermark]

watermark_filter = '[0:v][2:v]overlay=10:10'  

command = ffmpeg.output(*inputs, f"{PROJECT_PATH}/data/final-{file_id}.mp4", vf=[watermark_filter, "fps=10,format=yuv420p"],
                        preset="veryfast", shortest=None, r=10, max_muxing_queue_size=4000,
                        **additional_parameters)
command.overwrite_output().run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
```

This code, however, creates a video without any watermark in it. Can you see any error?

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg-python` has a built in support for `overlay` filter, that we may use for overlaying the logo.
For getting 50% opacity we may filter the logo with `format` filter chained with `colorchannelmixer` filter as described [here](https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-add-watermark-to-videos-using-ffmpeg/).

---

Let start with the `amix` filter (seems unrelated to the question):
`amix` filter requires two input streams - we should to put the two inputs in a list.

```
second_audio = f'{PROJECT_PATH}/data/ppt-elements/second_audio_{file_id}.txt'  # Assume there is a second audio list file named "second_audio_1.txt"
second_audio_input = ffmpeg.input(second_audio, f='concat', safe=0, t=seconds).audio  # Second audio input to amix filter
amix_filtered_input = ffmpeg.filter([audio_input, second_audio_input], "amix", inputs=2, duration="longest")  # amix filter requires 2 inputs (put them in a list).
```

---

Adding the watermark:

- Define the watermark_file (`logo.png`) as input video:

  ```
   watermark_file = f"{PROJECT_PATH}/data/logo/logo.png"
   watermark_input = ffmpeg.input(watermark_file).video  # Define watermark_file as input video
  ```
- Apply `format` filter chained with `colorchannelmixer` filter for getting 50% opacity:

  ```
   opacity_watermark_input = ffmpeg.filter(watermark_input, "format", pix_fmts='rgba').filter("colorchannelmixer", aa=0.5)
  ```
- Apply `overlay` filter:
  The first input is the imases.
  The second input is the filtered logo.

  ```
   watermark_filtered_input = ffmpeg.overlay(image_input, opacity_watermark_input, x=10, y=10)
  ```
- Define a list of inputs.
  The first input is the overlaid video (with the logo).
  The second input is the "amix"ed filtered audio.

  ```
   inputs = [watermark_filtered_input, amix_filtered_input]
  ```
- Define FFmpeg command, and run:
  Note: the `r=10` moved to the input.

  ```
   command = ffmpeg.output(*inputs, f"{PROJECT_PATH}/data/final-{file_id}.mp4",
                           preset="veryfast", shortest=None, max_muxing_queue_size=4000,
                           **additional_parameters)

   command.overwrite_output().run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import ffmpeg

PROJECT_PATH = 'c:/Tmp/ffmpeg'
file_id = 1
seconds = 10
fps = 10

audio = f'{PROJECT_PATH}/data/ppt-elements/audio_{file_id}.txt'
images = f'{PROJECT_PATH}/data/ppt-elements/images_{file_id}.txt'

image_input = ffmpeg.input(images, r=fps, f='concat', safe=0, t=seconds).video  # For images, the r=10 is part of the input (since images does't have framerate) 
audio_input = ffmpeg.input(audio, f='concat', safe=0, t=seconds).audio

additional_parameters = {'c:a': 'aac', 'c:v': 'libx264'}

second_audio = f'{PROJECT_PATH}/data/ppt-elements/second_audio_{file_id}.txt'  # Assume there is a second audio list file named "second_audio_1.txt"
second_audio_input = ffmpeg.input(second_audio, f='concat', safe=0, t=seconds).audio  # Second audio input to amix filter
amix_filtered_input = ffmpeg.filter([audio_input, second_audio_input], "amix", inputs=2, duration="longest")  # amix filter requires 2 inputs (put them in a list).

# Add watermark
watermark_file = f"{PROJECT_PATH}/data/logo/logo.png"
watermark_input = ffmpeg.input(watermark_file).video  # Define watermark_file as input video

#watermark = ffmpeg.input(watermark_file)
#inputs = [image_input, audio_input, watermark]
#watermark_filter = '[0:v][2:v]overlay=10:10'

# Define the overlay filter
#watermark_filtered_input = ffmpeg.overlay(image_input, watermark_input, x=10, y=10) # Without 50% opacity.
opacity_watermark_input = ffmpeg.filter(watermark_input, "format", pix_fmts='rgba').filter("colorchannelmixer", aa=0.5)  # Chain format filter with colorchannelmixer filter for getting 50% opacity
watermark_filtered_input = ffmpeg.overlay(ffmpeg.filter(image_input, "setpts", expr=f'N/{fps}/TB'), opacity_watermark_input, x=10, y=10)  # Add setpts filter to image_input for fixing the timestamps

inputs = [watermark_filtered_input, amix_filtered_input]  # List of inputs: video input is the overlaid filter, and the audio is "amix"ed filter

command = ffmpeg.output(*inputs, f"{PROJECT_PATH}/data/final-{file_id}.mp4",
                        preset="veryfast", shortest=None, max_muxing_queue_size=4000,
                        **additional_parameters)  # May add .global_args('-report') for debugging

command.overwrite_output().run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
```

---

Sample video frame (downscaled):
[image]